# null pointer exception - image capture

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm a beginner. Didn't know where I messed up. So any help is much appreciated.
The 2nd activity has a button with intent to open 3rd activity. The 3rd activity should start to open with the camera function and wait for an image to be captured before being displayed. However the 3rd activity failed as soon as it started. 
So here is the code.

Java code(2nd activity).

```
public class CameraView extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_view);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
}

public void onClickCam(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Java code(3rd activity).

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {

private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;
private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
private ImageView mImageView;
private Bitmap mImageBitmap;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;

/* Photo album for this application */
private String getAlbumName() {
    return getString(R.string.album_name);
}

private File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (! storageDir.exists()){
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }

    return storageDir;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}

private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

    File f = createImageFile();
    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

    return f;
}

private void setPic() {

    /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
    /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

    /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}


private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    switch(actionCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;          
    } // switch

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}

private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

    if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
        setPic();
        galleryAddPic();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mImageBitmap = null;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
    startActivity(intent);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
    } else {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleBigCameraPhoto();
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B
    } // switch
}


// Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );

    }


/**
 * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
 * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
 * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
 * found, this method returns false.
 * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
 *
 * @param context The application's environment.
 * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
 *
 * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
 *         responded to, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}

}
```

XML code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ResultActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

LogCat

```
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camoid/com.example.camoid.ResultActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.getAlbumDir(ResultActivity.java:47)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.createImageFile(ResultActivity.java:69)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.setUpPhotoFile(ResultActivity.java:76)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(ResultActivity.java:135)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:171)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

Comment: Please post your Intent. (How do you start the activity?)

Comment: You cut off the logcat at its critical point :) `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` this is the NPE and the following lines would have told where it was occurring.

Comment: oh. my mistake. I'll edit it back.

Comment: What if I told you that you can debug and learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
startActivity(intent);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
    mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
} else {
    mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
}
```

Here `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` indirectly calls a function `getAlbumDir()`that uses `mAlbumStorageDirFactory` which is not initialized yet, as observed in the logcat:

```
08-26 01:45:55.845: E/AndroidRuntime(3471): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.getAlbumDir(ResultActivity.java:47)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.createImageFile(ResultActivity.java:69)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.setUpPhotoFile(ResultActivity.java:76)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(ResultActivity.java:135)
08-26 02:33:57.415: E/AndroidRuntime(3730):     at com.example.camoid.ResultActivity.onCreate(ResultActivity.java:171)
```

Set up `mAlbumStorageDirFactory` before calling `dispatchTakePictureIntnet()`.

Comment: You're right. I've skipped one process. The dispatch should trigger image_capture before selecting action_take_photo_b.

Answer (score 1):

**A complete working solution**

```
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
private String imgPath;

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });


public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities. Either you a) forgot to declare your second activity in your manifest or b) your Intent which starts the second activity is incorrect.

**If a)**

You need the following inside of your `<application>` tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".ResultActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

**If b)**

This is one way to start an activity:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class), 0);
```